# in tibco bw6 how to create a logic in mapper

Tags: logic, tibco, mapper

I have created a databasein my sql below is the table:

| Seq_id | Order_id | Product | ExpiryDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | Bread | 2023-04-08 |
| 2 | 123 | Rice | 2023-04-05 |
| 3 | 321 | Rice | 2023-05-25 |
| 4 | 123 | Curd | 2023-04-03 |
| 5 | 342 | Sugar | 2023-04-15 |
| 6 | 342 | Oil | 2023-04-11 |
| 7 | 342 | Pasta | 2023-04-13 |
| 8 | 342 | Soups | 2023-04-10 |
| 8 | 342 | Toast | 2023-03-16 |

And the data is coming in XML format inside mapper

I have tried 3 ways are as follows:

1. [days-from-duration(current-date() - tns13:Expiry_Date) < 5]
2. [days-from-duration(xsd:date(substring-before(xsd:string(current-date()),"+")) - tns3:ExpiryDate)          < 5]
3. [tib:add-to-date(current-date() - tns13:Expiry_Date) < 5]

I was expecting a output in which the expiry date is less than  5 days from the current date.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you using JDBC Query activity or SQL Direct activity ? Can you attach a screen shot of your mapping ? One thing also is that if the requirement is to filter rows from the database the filtering can be done in the SQL Query